# VHDL error in for generate

Tags: loops, for-loop, vhdl, xilinx

I'm a newbie user of VHDL.

I have an error in this code:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity AandB is

Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);

       b : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0);

salida : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(31 downto 0)

          );

end AandB;

architecture Behavioral of AandB is

begin

for i in 0 to 31 loop

    salida(i) <= a(i) and b(i);

end loop;

end Behavioral;
```

the error is this:

```
 ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Line 43: Syntax error near "for".

 ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 -  Line 45: <i> is not declared.

 ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Line 47: Syntax error near "generate".

 ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - Line 39: Unit <behavioral> ignored due to previous errors.
```

I have searched for the enter code here`first 3 errors. Haven't noticed what is the syntax error for the "for" statement; It's supposed that  is indirectly declared within the loop; Don't know about the error in "generate".

Some help?

Comment: For...loops can't be outside a process. For...Generate statements can, but must (a) start with a label and (b) have the word Generate somewhere. Using a For loop outside a process has convinced the compiler you're using a (broken) For...Generate statement, confusing it.

Comment: In addition to Jim showing you the syntax of a generate statement that will elaborate to a block statement containing 32 blocks with 32 processes you could also use a concurrent simple assignment:  `salida <= a and b'; which elaborates to one process. You could also put your for loop in a process statement and get the same effect.

Comment: I m not sure if the TS knows what `generate` is. Could be that we should also explain how a `process` statement works.

Answer (score 0):

```
ThirtyTwoAnd: for i in 0 to 31 generate

    salida(i) <= a(i) and b(i);

end generate ThirtyTwoAnd;
```

Comment: Jim's answer provides two things.  A generate statement must have a label, and a generate statement uses the reserved word generate and not loop.

Answer (score 0):

What Jim said can even be simplified. `ieee.std_logic_1164` actually defines:

```
FUNCTION "and"  ( l,r : std_logic_vector ) RETURN std_logic_vector;
```

So you could in this case of equal length vectors just write:

```
salida <= "and"(a, b);
```

But just this will also work:

```
salida <= a and b;
```